# How to Access Meta Data Via Webhooks for Stripe Test Subscription?

Tags: node.js, metadata, webhooks

[image]I see you can manually add key/value pairs now to Stripe like in my example image.

Does anyone have an example of using a nodejs webhook to grab that data?

[Their tool to build the webhook](https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks/create?events=checkout.session.completed) doesn't show how to access the meta data.

Thanks

I'm not sure how to reference the meta data value pairs sent to the webhook.